# How to add 3 months to a UTC time stamp in javascript centered at midnight 00 Hours?

Tags: javascript, datetime, utc

I am trying to add 3 months to today's date in a javascript. This is my code:

```
    var now = new Date();
    now.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);;
    now.setMinutes(0);

    var plus3mo = new Date();
    plus3mo.setMonth((now.getMonth() + 3));
    plus3mo.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    plus3mo.setMinutes(0);

    var utc_timestamp_today = Date.UTC(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var utc_timestamp_3moFromNow = Date.UTC(plus3mo.getFullYear(), plus3mo.getMonth(), plus3mo.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I want to add exactly 3 months to today's date and have the hours. It is doing that, but the catch is I need the hours to be set to exactly 00 hours or 12am. I am getting weird results with the code I have.

Here are my results that I viewed while debugging and using this [UTC time stamp converter site](http://www.timestampconvert.com/?go2=true&offset=4&timestamp=1449792000000&Submit=%20%20%20%20%20%20Convert%20to%20Date%20%20%20%20%20%20).

```
1441929600000  --> 09/10/2015 20:00:00     ("Today's Date")
1449792000000  --> 12/10/2015 19:00:00     ("3 Months From Now")
```

As you can see, I am adding 3 months, but the hours are centered at 8pm and 7pm. Why is this happening?

Comment: Daylight savings time adjustment? Your span crosses that boundary.

Comment: and note that adding months is highly weird, even if you ignore DST issues. what's "Nov 30 + 3 months"? `Feb 30` doesn't exist...

Comment: @MarcB JS Date object calculates a correct date in case of `Feb 30` too.

Comment: All great points, so than the day is correct, but my issue now is that I need the dates to all be reset to 00 Hours on the 24-hour clock (aka Midnight). All data-points in my MySQL database are at 00 Hours so a time of "19:00:00" could potentially cause an error.

Comment: I thought that "  .setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
   and  .setMinutes(0);" should do that? I can't have my codes remain at 8pm and 7pm, they both need to be set to 12 midnight.

Comment: Guys, sorry, I see my issue, this is GMT/UTC and it really is 00 Hours (GMT). The online converters keep showing me local time. I apologize, stupid mistake!

Comment: simply set the hours and mins to zero  AFTER you set the month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using date manipulation in JS always gives you a date relative to the local time of the browser. So using

```
var now = new Date();
now.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
now.setMinutes(0);
```

Will give you a date in `now` that is at midnight for your local time, but is at your local timezone offset relative to UTC. (I assume this is currently +4 hours currently and changes to +5hours) when daylight savings kicks in for the winter.

In order to get midnight UTC for each date, I'd suggest:

1. getting the UTC date timestamp from each Date using [getTime/valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)
2. determining the offest using [getTimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)
3. convert the offset from minutes to milliseconds (multiply by 60000) and subtract from the original timestamp
4. use [setTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime) on each date object if you need the Date objects in their original locale but at midnight UTC